# libcurl: how to use TPM private key for mutual SSL authentication

Tags: ssl, openssl, tpm, ocsp, curl

I use the C libcurl library. 
I need to do OCSP stapling combined with mutual authentication. For that, I'll take model on the below exemples. However, I need the private key of my client certificate to be stored in the TPM chip. Do you know how to do that, using tpm2-tss-engine? Thanks for your help.

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-ssl.html
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLCERT.html

Comment: This is a programming question for stack overflow. And separate into two questions, because OCSP and TLS client auth with a TPM have nothing to do with each other. You can search for how to use TPM for ssh auth, it's the same thing. There are pkcs11 API wrapper for TPM2 which should make it easier. You will need to store the private key encrypted by TPM yourself, because TPM doesn't have enough storage.

Comment: The very first question is : how can libcurl (in C) read the private key of a certificate in a TPM, for authentication purpose.

Comment: The whole point of a key in a TPM is that the key cannot ever leave the TPM in a usable way. The TPM must perform the signatures. openssl has a way to use  "engines" which use external devices like smart cards to perform signatures using keys in the devices, and this can be done during the handshake. TPM is complicated, you are not going to get a 1 minute explanation. You need to read a lot about it.

Answer (score 2):

I was able use a key stored in TPM with `openssl s_client` (maybe it is possible with curl), but am able to make a HTTPS request and receive a response.

`openssl` allows you to read the key from the TPM. you can use the command `s_client` to connect via a TCP, then send your HTTP request.

Example command would look like:

File: http_request.txt (with two newlines at the end)

```
GET /url/path HTTP/1.0
Host: hostname.com
```

```
cat http_request.txt | \
openssl s_client \
  -nocommands \
  -ign_eof \
  -msgfile /dev/null \
  -quiet \
  -keyform engine \
  -engine pkcs11 \
  -cert mycertificate.pem \
  -CAfile root.ca.pem \
  -key 'pkcs11:model=SWTPM;manufacturer=Intel;token=mytoken;object=myobject;type=private;pin-value=mypin' \
  -connect hostname.com:443
```

This allows me to use TPM to make requests to AWS IoT: `iot:AssumeRoleWithCertificate` which assumes the key is a file on disk: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/authorizing-direct-aws.html

Comment: Thanks. How do you specify a TPM handle ?

Comment: ```p11tool --list-tokens``` Will show all of your tokens including the url/"handle", assuming you have already created them. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/p11tool.1.html

Comment: What if for example my private key is on TPM handle 0x8100000009 ?